# Is the Haskell operator * a combination of + operators?

Tags: haskell, operators

How does Haskell's `*` work? Does it create a series of `+` operators, or does it do something else?

Comment: It works in whichever way the corresponding `Num` instance defines it. If you want to have multiplication on your custom type to create a series of `+`, you can do that... but of course that's very inefficient, none of the standard instances do it this way.

Comment: Since you can perform `x * y` on `Double`s, it can not be only the result of summing up `x` or `y`.

Comment: It's only *expected*, not actually *required*, that `*` and `+` together obey distributivity (in the sense that Haskell cannot determine if the law is obeyed). Distributivity (`x * (y + z) == x * y + x * z` and `(y + z) * x == y * x + z * x`) is what implies that multiplication is repeated addition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the `Num` type class

```
type  Num :: Type -> Constraint
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  -- .. I'm omitting the other methods
```

This is how `Num` is defined for `Int` ([src](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Num.html))

```
instance Num Int where
  (+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
  I# x + I# y = I# (x +# y)

  (*) :: Int -> Int -> Int
  I# x * I# y = I# (x *# y)
  -- ..
```

This is how it's defined for `Float` ([src](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.0.1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/src/GHC-Float.html))

```
instance Num Float where
  (+) :: Float -> Float -> Float
  F# x + F# y = F# (plusFloat# x y)

  (*) :: Float -> Float -> Float
  F# x * F# y = F# (timesFloat# x y)
```

Maybe not enlightening but you can see that (for those instances) they are defined in terms of primitive operations like `(+#)` or `timesFloat#`. If you define your own number you can define multiplication in terms of repeated addition but the operations are not fundamentally defined that way.

```
type N :: Type
data N = O | S N

instance Num N where
  (+) :: N -> N -> N
  O   + m = m
  S n + m = S (n + m)

  (*) :: N -> N -> N
  O   * _ = O
  S n * m = m + (n * m)
```

You can define a "default" multiplication function that is defined in terms of repeated additions

```
-- >> timesViaPlus @Int @Int 10 20
-- 200
-- >> timesViaPlus @Integer @Integer 10 20
-- 200
timesViaPlus :: Integral n => Num m => n -> m -> m
timesViaPlus n m = sum (fromIntegral n `replicate` m)
```

or you could specialize it to `N` and use it to define `(*) @N`.

```
replicateN :: N -> a -> [a]
replicateN O     _ = []
replicateN (S n) a = a : replicateN n a

timesViaPlusN :: Num n => N -> n -> n
timesViaPlusN n m = sum (n `replicateN` m)

instance Num N where
  (+) :: N -> N -> N
  O   + m = m
  S n + m = S (n + m)

  (*) :: N -> N -> N
  (*) = timesViaPlusN
```